# CPU slaves on a PCI card to retrofit single processor to multiple processors. Any ideas how?

Tags: cpu, rom, motherboard, overclocking

My desktop computer is no longer manufactured and no longer supported since more than 18 years ago. It was a very expensive top of the line business computer back in the day. I like it and wish to preserve it, but also continue to use it. It takes a single processor on the main board (with up to 4 GB of memory). However, what I wanted to know is if anyone has any idea of how I can add additional slave processors (and possibly RAM) to this system through the mainboard's PCI card slots, and thereby up the processing power of this machine? Also, is there a way to overclock the processor or otherwise to further up it's performance? I am also factoring in the tons of old computers going into land fills in this question so that if this problem can be solved economically, then many old computers might be able to be retrofitted, preserved, and to be usable again with modern operating systems and softwares.

Comment: PCs cannot do this. Are you trying to design your own completely new computer system?

Comment: Because I have seen it somewhere, what I had in mind was a single board PC that connected to my computer via the PCI card slot, and worked in tandem in processing power with my computer as a slave. I know that computers can be networked together for distributed computing. So I thought that through a PCI card this might be accomplished. What or where would I go to look to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Oh that's probably possible, I don't know if someone's designed one, I don't know why they would sell them, and I don't know if the question is on-topic for this site (but I doubt it).

Comment: Also, there are PCI boards that have CPUs on them for industrial machines, like seen here: http://international.electronica-azi.ro/2018/04/04/long-live-isa-pci/ but I am not sure where I can find CPU processing boards to add into a desktop machine to increase from a single motherboad processor to effectively making a multi-processor machine from additional processors through a PCI card slot. Then once that is accomplished, to then overclock the processors or something, to make them scream performance.

Comment: To clarify, when I said, "networked together for distributed computing", that is to say the PCI card single board PC (with multiple processors preferably) would be internally doing distributed computing as a slave to my retro computer from 2003. It does not have to be this, but this is just one idea. The objective is to retrofit a single processor legacy machine to be effectively a machine with multiple processors working in tandem.

Comment: It's not exactly a "retrofit" if you connect it to a brand new computer, I think. That's taking a new computer and putting it in an old computer case.

Comment: There are SBC PCs on expansion boards, using PCI mostly for their power supply, but they are quite a bit more expensive than equivalent PCs (even SFF PCs). Apart from the space savings I don’t see any advantage, and it might not even work anyway — any decently powerful PC on an expansion card will probably require more cooling than your SFF PC can provide.

Comment: Current PCs are *so* much faster than 2003-vintage PCs that there’s not much point in trying to make anything that old “scream performance”.

Comment: Hello all. Thanks. I'm looking for ideas for how it can be possible and done. I'm not stuck on one idea particularly... just grasp the concept of **retrofit a single processor legacy machine to be effectively a machine with multiple processors working in tandum**. Plus, current machines use lower processors at 2.4 or less Ghz, but are multiple processors combined in one chip... that's what makes them more effective. Mine is 3.4Ghz single processor, but if made multiple by a PCI card (i.e. 3.4Ghz or something), that makes it roughly comparable to "current PCs" (with some minor drawbacks).

Comment: @user253751 I think yes, PCs could do this - except that, as far I know, no one developed it. PCI cards *have* access to system memory, although it is slower than the memory access of the main CPU. This will result a NUMA system with a main CPU, having quick & fast access to the main RAM, and secondary CPU(s) having quick access to their own RAM on the card, and slow access to the main RAM. It would require also custom drivers, both for the inter-cpu communication and for the memory management. This was not developed, but it would be possible.

Comment: @Mr.Lopez my current-generation 2.7GHz system is faster on single-threaded tasks than my 7-year-old 3.4GHz Haswell system, so no, even though your 17-year-old CPU has a high clock rate, it’s not “roughly comparable” to current PCs. Current CPUs do a lot more per clock, per core (and per thread), than 2003-vintage CPUs.

Comment: What is it you really want to achieve? Your proposal sounds like a very costly way to improve performance of a very old machine, which can be done more cheaply by just replacing the entire system (or possibly just the motherboard, CPU and memory) with an up-to-date one. The HP Compaq DC5100 SFF is an unremarkable desktop PC otherwise, or is there a reason you can't replace it? This has all the hallmarks of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Agree with the close - 2003 + XP is not really Retro. But I did come up with a true Retro *answer*.

Comment: My petition is to reopen this question because the question is indeed about computer systems that are no longer manufactured and no longer supported. This isn't just a question of my current PC (that is now more than 18 years old), because I'm also factoring in the tons of old computers going into land fills in this question so that if this problem can be solved economically, then many old computers might be able to be retrofitted, resurrected, preserved, and to be usable again with modern operating systems and softwares. That's why I believe my question is indeed on topic for retro computing.

Comment: @Mr.Lopez while that’s a laudable goal, expanding your question to attempt to solve all the problems caused by the processing of obsolete hardware doesn’t make it any more [on-topic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). “Preserving” as in “expanding my old computer so it’s a modern computer” isn’t really “preserving” as a retrocomputing topic IMO. And the economic side of things would be better addressed in other venues.

Comment: Respecfully all, I disagree with the conclusion. Nevertheless, if there is a forum anyone can suggest where this question would be more better suited, I am open to any suggestions. Please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CompuPro did this in the olden days, with 8-bit and 16-bit CPU slave cards with a 16-bit or 32-bit main CPU. But there were a few differences from what you are suggesting:

- Each CPU had its own RAM. That was an absolute must. If two CPUs have to share RAM (except to a limited degree - e.g., DMA for disk access), they will slow each other down. RAM is already the slow point in many systems, and keep in mind that if other CPUs are using the main CPU's RAM then you also mess up the caching that is key to modern CPUs being able to run at multi-GHz speeds.
- Multi-user systems. Actually, we do this today, in a sense, by using multi-core CPUs with multiple users over a network. But in the olden days this was typically multiple serial terminals. A typical system might have one master CPU, multiple slave CPUs, a disk controller card, a general I/O card and a *multiple serial-port card*. Each terminal connected to one serial port and the operating system would provide a console interface and run programs on either the main CPU or a slave CPU as appropriate. Today's systems have most connections dedicated, in which case one user = one CPU, and if that one user needs a faster CPU then they upgrade to a newer machine. The exceptions (sometimes in offices, but especially in data centers) are networked machines where if you need more power you don't upgrade the tiny little box, you throw more boxes and/or bigger boxes at the problem.

The other big difference is motherboard vs. passive backplane. The S-100 was the classic passive backplane system. It was essentially a spur-of-the-moment design for the Altair, but it lasted quite a while. 8080 2 MHz not fast enough, replace with a Z80 4 MHz. But possibly upgrade your RAM at the same time. Need more ports, swap the I/O card. Need more RAM on an 8086, add another card or trade in the 256K card for 1M card. But that had limits. Looking to CompuPro again, when they came out with an 80386 CPU, they couldn't get the CPU-RAM interface fast enough while remaining anywhere close to S-100 specs. So instead of making the existing cards useless, they came up with a second bus **connecting only the 80386 CPU and RAM cards** but continued using the existing bus for slave CPUs and I/O.

One more factor is that the latest and greatest (and fastest) CPU chips are a large part of the cost of a new system. That was not always the case, but it is today. So unless you have a high-end laptop (in which case your options are limited anyway), almost always the most cost-effective thing to do is to get an entirely new computer with a super-fast CPU & RAM and reuse your monitor(s) and other external peripherals and, if you already have large/fast SSDs, your storage.

Answer (score 7):

> how I can add additional slave processors (and possibly RAM) to this system through the mainboard's PCI card slots

While DMA works through PCI, this is not practical to sustain to have additional CPUs on the card access main memory.

So basically you'd need a complete second PC with RAM and one or more CPUs on the card. The best you can hope for is to use the PCI memory window either for shared memory with a small part of the on-card RAM, or as a sort of I/O control of the card.

That means it's not much different from having two completely separate PCs connected via LAN, say.

On top of that, you'd have to develop some PCI slave controller for that purpose, you'd have to develop and manufacture the whole card. But the card's electronics will be dense enough that you can not easily do this as a hobbyist, and the numbers produced are too low to make this less than horribly expensive.

So no, it's not a practical way to "improve processing power" of your legacy system.

Though designs like this existed in the past for older platforms (both with and without shared main memory), it just doesn't make sense for PCI-equipped PC.

Comment: Can you go into some more detail as to why DMA over PCI would not be enough to let another CPU access the main RAM? Because I think that’s the most interesting part.

Comment: @user3840170 too slow, possibly?

Comment: Right, I forgot they had to invent AGP so that a graphics card could access memory with reasonable performance. I guess a whole other CPU would face something similar.

Comment: And the two CPUs would have to coordinate memory caches somehow. I don’t think that’s trivial to do over PCI.

Comment: @user3840170: That's already handled. It's routine for things like high-end disc controllers to use bus-mastering to transfer data to and from main memory and the CPU will "peek" at transactions to assure that if it has that data dirty in the cache, it'll be flushed before the disc controller reads it. But yes, without direct CPU-CPU connections, it gets pretty slow.